# VIntWritable vs IntWritable

Tags: hadoop, compression

I understand that [VIntWritable](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/VIntWritable.html) can significantly reduce the size needed to store an integer, when compared to [IntWritable](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/IntWritable.html).

My questions are: What is the cost of using VIntWritable instead of IntWritable? Is it (only) the time needed for compression? In other words, when should I use IntWritable, instead of VIntWritable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do you choose between a fixed-length and a variable-length
>   encoding?
>
> Fixedlength encodings are good when the distribution of values is
>   fairly uniform across the whole value space, such as a (well-designed)
>   hash function. Most numeric variables tend to have nonuniform
>   distributions, and on average the variable-length encoding will save
>   space. Another advantage of variable-length encodings is that you can
>   switch from VIntWritable to VLongWritable, because their encodings are
>   actually the same. So by choosing a variable-length representation,
>   you have room to grow without committing to an 8-byte long
>   representation from the beginning.

I just picked this up from the [definitive guide book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449311520) page 98

Comment: Very useful! I should have gone back to the book first... Any intuition on WHY is fixed-length encoding preferred when the distribution is unifrom? I mean, why not use a VIntWritable there, too?

Comment: My guess is that this is very similar to char and varchar debate from the RDBMS world, in certain cases i think that fixed width will give better performance as it will use some kind of static memory allocation versus variable-length which will need to use dynamic memory allocation. In a nutshell the pro's and con's which apply to char and varchar will apply to hadoop as well